# Unknown column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Unknown column 'Abu' in 'field list'
So here is a little comment box I am working on
http://abu.cpvp.net/cupcakes.php
WHen I put in my name and comment it won't work, however if I put in name for name field and comment for comment field it works????
Here is my script

```
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$comment=$_POST['comment']; 
$submit=$_POST['post'];
if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['comment']  && $submit) 
{ 
    $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comment (`name`,`comment`) 
                         VALUES ($name,$comment) " ) or die(mysql_error()); 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "please fill out all fields"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the data type of the columns are string, then the value should be wrapped with single quotes as they are string literals,

```
INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Wow thanks! 
Yeah I would prefer using PDO but my host doesn't offer it. Sadly..
I will look into how to prevent SQL injections. Thanks for the link!

Comment: So my only question would with the SQL thing I just make it a non-direct entry? 
$dbconnection(    )

Comment: you can also use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) but this has been discourage since it will be deprecated on `PHP 5.5.0`

Comment: I am going to use PDO, less hassle. Plus more simple. Personal rule keep it simple...

Comment: [KISS - Keep It Simple Sailor] `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put strings in quotes:

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment 
(name,comment) 
VALUES ($name,$comment) " )
```

should be

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment 
(name,comment) 
VALUES ('$name','$comment') " )
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Yeah I'll make my code more modern. I am just getting back into coding PHP, and the last time I used was circa fall of '10.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')
```

Will solve your issue.. But something the other developers might have noticed, but not pointed out.. You have not closed a backtick of your SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO `comment
```

Should be:

```
INSERT INTO `comment`
```

there is nothing wrong in using backticks for column/table/schema names.. Infact they are recommended, to minimize the risk of running into a **SQL Reserved Word**.. Providing they are open/closed correctly

Comment: Not sure what an SQL Reserved word is, however done. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @user2288998 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html  this reviews possible error messages and gives an oversight of what i mean by reserved words